# Incrementing integers

Tags: ceylon

I'm having some trouble incrementing a variable integer. This code:

```
variable Integer myInteger = -1;
Integer getInteger () {
    myInteger = myInteger + 1;
    print("myInteger: " + myInteger.string);
    return Integer(myInteger);
}

Array<Integer> integers =
        Array.ofSize(
            4,
            getInteger());

print(integers);
```

Gives this output:

```
myInteger: 0
{ 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

while the intended output was:

```
myInteger: 0
myInteger: 1
myInteger: 2
myInteger: 3
{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }
```

What's up with that?

Comment: Ah I see it now: Array.ofSize doesn't take a callback, and even if it did, I shouldn't execute the callback as I pass it as argument to Array.ofSize

Comment: I want to close this question, but apparently I'm not sufficiently powerful

Comment: By the way there's no need to init a new Integer in `return Integer(myInteger);` because Integers are immutable. Just `return myInteger` will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example, which I assume is contrived, can be written as `Array(0:4)` or `Array(0..3)`. But assuming that you have some good reason to want to loop over a generating function, here is how I would write it:

```
Array(loop(0)((i) => i+1).take(4))
```

Or, equivalently:

```
Array(loop(0)(Integer.successor).take(4))
```

Or even:

```
Array(loop(0)(1.plus).take(4))
```

That's much better, IMO, than using a stream which accesses a variable in an outer scope.

Answer (score 3):

You already found what is happening here ... the constructor `Array.ofSize(n, val)` is creating an array filled with `n` times the same value.

A way of doing what you want might be this:

```ceylon
Array<Integer> integers =
        Array({ getInteger() }.repeat(4));
```

([Try it.](http://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=6206d77c7c7a74d34851b2a563a9206d))

The expression in the iterable enumeration (this is the `{ getInteger() }` here) is evaluated lazily each time the iterator's next method is invoked (which is happening 4 times here, due to repeating the iterable 4 times).

Note that it won't work if you use a sequence enumeration `[ ... ]` instead, those are non-lazy.